# Stack overflow error in javascript when recursively scrolling to the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, dom, twitter, recursion

I am trying to recursively scroll to the bottom of a twitter page until the page shows all of the followers for a user. Each time it gets to the bottom it will load another segment until there are none left to load.

```
function findStats(){
   a = $("a.js-nav");
   for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
     if(a[i].dataset.elementTerm === "follower_stats"){
        return a[i];}
     }
}

numberOfFol = function() {
    return Number(findStats().innerText.match(/\d+/)[0]);
}


var bottom = function(){
    scrollTo(0,document.height - $(window).height());
    if($(".fullname.js-action-profile-name").length<numberOfFol()){
        bottom();
    }
}
```

I've tried a non-recursive version of bottom() with loops and every time the page freezes and on my last recursive attempt, the console finally threw a maxiumum stack size exceeded error. I tried setTimeout in a loop as well given that the page takes it's time to load but the same thing happened(this was with the non-recursive bottom function). The non-recursive bottom function is

```
var bottom = function(){scrollTo(0,document.height - $(window).height())}
```

Even stranger is the fact that if I call the non-recursive bottom function by itself, it works fine and goes to the bottom of the page with no trouble(only once of course).

Why are these functions overflowing the stack when recursed/in loops?

Comment: have you tried setting a breakpoint in the developer tools so you can see the values being returned by `numberOfFol()`?

Comment: You have to wait for the new items to be loaded and displayed before calling bottom again. Use a timer, not recursion.